# Erro ao criar plataforma com Cordova em Ubuntu (ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android")

Tags: apache-cordova, ubuntu, ionic

Antes de tudo, confesso que sou iniciante no Linux e atualmente uso o Elementary OS Luna atualizado. Então está sendo bem complicado pra mim resolver isso.

Consegui instalar toda a stack NPM (Ionic, cordova, angular.js) e o Java tranquilo. Só que na hora de instalar o Android SDK tools (sem IDE) no ubuntu achei muito complicado então usei [esse shell script](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/09/install-android-cordova-ionic-framework-ubuntu/) pra instalar tudo automaticamente.

Funcionou, instalei o SDK, mas na hora de criar a plataforma no IONIC da esse erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Isso](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26216081/4056678)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa setar a variável de ambiente `ANDROID_HOME` com o caminho do local de instalação da SDK do Android.

Edite o arquivo `.profile` no seu diretório home:

```
nano ~/.profile
```

Adicione as seguintes linhas:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/caminho-do-sdk/android-sdk/
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms-tools
```

Para salvar o arquivo no `nano` é só apertar <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd> e depois <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Depois disso reinicie o terminal ou digite

```
source ~/.profile
```

para carregar as variáveis que você acabou de setar.

**UPDATE:**

Caso tenha executado o comando como root (sudo, etc.), alguns diretórios em `$HOME/.cordova` e o diretório do seu projeto vão estar sem permissão de escrita por terem sido criados pelo root.

Para resolver basta um `chown` como root para recuperar a propriedade:

```
$ sudo chown -R USUARIO:USUARIO /home/[USUARIO]/.cordova
$ sudo chown -R USUARIO:USUARIO /caminho/do/projeto/
```

Comment: Cara, eu não sei qual é o caminho-do-sdk

Comment: @ropbla9 Você baixou o [SDK do Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other)?

Comment: sim. e instalei pelo script que eu te disse. Mas não sei onde ele está. Não da pra você ver na imagem que te mostrei? Tem a pasta .android (oculta) na home, só isso

Comment: Ah, tem uma pasta chamada /opt/android-sdk.

Comment: @ropbla9 Provavelmente é a `/opt/android-sdk` mesmo. A `.android` guarda configurações e outras coisas que o sdk usa.

Comment: pois é man. Fiz como vc disse e não funcionou.

Comment: Antes de adicionar o que vc colocou estava configurado assim > 
`export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/node/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java` Dai nas ultimas linhas ainda adicionei o seu.

Comment: Você está executando isso com `sudo`? Se estiver edite o .profile do root com `sudo nano /root/profile`.

Comment: Esse arquivo tá vazio. E editar com o que?

Comment: Adiciona essas mesmas duas linhas que eu falei na resposta.

Comment: deu nada cara. Tentei dar source nesse do root mas n da.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20917/discussion-between-andre-ribeiro-and-ropbla9).

Comment: o problema foi resolvido?