# Variavel de Ambiente ANDROID_HOME Linux

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova, variáveis

Estou tem problema com a variavel de ambiente ANDROID_HOME, sempre que tento executar o comando para rodar um app no emulador (ou celular conectado), aparece essa mensagem de erro

```
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.
```

Ja tentei varias coisas que vi na internet e nada funcionou, alguem conseguiria me ajudar? 
Estou utilizando o Deepin Linux.

Ao executar `echo $ANDROID_HOME` o resultado é `/home/rafael/Android/Sdk`

Quando dou `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/android-sdk/platform-tools:/opt/android-sdk/tools:/home/rafael/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/home/rafael/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/rafael/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/rafael/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/rafael/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49847/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/176032/3635

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É preciso rodar os comandos:

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

Neste arquivo é preciso adicionar os seguintes comandos:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=caminho_do_SDK
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Salvar e recarregar o arquivo.bashrc:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou, eu coloquei no arquivo como você falou, mas da o mesmo erro. Atualizei o post pra você ver o que acontece quando dou echo no $PATH

Comment: não use sudo para editar o arquivo do usuario. isso vai bloquear as permissões para o root.

Comment: Me loguei só para agradecer, melhor solução que encontei... :)

Comment: Estou com o mesmo problema mas com o CentOs 7, fiz tudo o que diz aqui e não funcionou nada.

Comment: No meu caso eu coloquei o EXPORT em ~/.zshrc